# Constructors infinite cycle in cpp

Tags: c++, constructor, cycle

I have a `Logger` *singleton class* that its purpose is to print messages to log file / screen.
This Logger has some configurations that he wants to read from configuration file. Here is the constructor of Logger:

```
Logger::Logger(const std::string& confFilePath) {
    m_logConf = new LogConfig(confFilePath);
    ...
}
```

Class `LogConfig` uses Configuration Object that knows how to parse a configuration file. Here is the class `Ctor`:

```
LogConfig::LogConfig(const std::string& confFilePath) {
    m_config = new Configuration(confFilePath);
    ...
    m_config->ParseConfFile();
}
```

The problem is that in `ParseConfFile` method - Configuration object may want to write to the log and use Logger singleton class. But, when it tries to do it - he will enter again to Logger constructor, and then to LogConfig Ctor and there is an infinite cycle.

I don't want to forbid Configuration class to write to the log (`LogConfig` is not the only class that uses it).

How can I solve this cycle problem?

Comment: sounds like chicken and egg. One has to be first, its your choice, but it cannot be both

Comment: Unless this is C++/CLI, it's not safe to be using `new` like that!  Ordinary C++ is _extremely_ different from Java in that regard.

Comment: @hegel5000 - why isn't it safe?

Comment: Because if you don't `delete` it somewhere yourself, then it'll never get deleted.  I realize that this is a singleton and it's supposed to last for as long as the program, but it's still better not to leave memory management up to chance.

Comment: If the static type of `m_logConf` is just `Configuration*`, then consider changing it to `Configuration`.  Then you can do `m_logConf = Configuration(confFilePath)`, without the `new`.  This will be deleted automatically.

Comment: I delete it on Logger destructor.. I didn't write it here, to reduce the redundant text.

Comment: If you don't use a pointer, then you can eliminate both `new` and `delete`, and not have to worry about potentially forgetting the `delete`.

Comment: I don't see it problematic at all, and anyway it is not the case here..

Comment: Sorry, I keep re-editing my comments.  I should stop that.

Comment: If I didn't want to mess with pointers and leak memories - I would choose to write in other language. I'm writing in C++, so pointers and memory allocations are part of the game.

Comment: What C++ provides over other languages is that it works with far fewer pointers than other languages do.  Instead of an object pointing to several other objects, it can have its constituent parts be contiguously laid out.  This provides spacial locality, which can really speed things up.

Comment: OK, let's say I am convinced. How does it work for my problem?

Comment: `m_logConf` will have to be of type `LogConfig` instead of `LogConfig*` (or a pointer to its parent class; as long as it's not a pointer).  Now, a `Logger` object physically contains a `LogConfig`, and both objects' lifetimes are bound together.  To set `m_logConf` you would do `m_logConf = LogConfig(confFilePath)`.

Comment: An even better option for initialization is `Logger::Logger(const std::string& confFilePath) : LogConfig(confFilePath) {`

Comment: And how does it solve the cycle problem..?

Comment: It doesn't.  That's why I've been writing to the comments instead of writing an answer.  Sorry.  Sorin's solution is good, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Logger` is a singleton, supposedly all classes (including `Configuration`) access it through a static method(say `getInctance()`), and `Logger`'s constructor is private.  The right approach would be to simplify Logger's construction to bare minimum and move the setup/configuration logic from the constructor to `getInstance()`.

Something like:

```
static Logger* Logger::getInstance() {
    if (m_logger == nullptr) {
        m_logger = new Logger();  // remove configuration path passing from the constructor
        m_logger->setConfigPath(const std::string& confFilePath); // ok trying to write to Logger, at least from the perspective of not being stuck in construction loop
    }
    return m_logger;
}
```

Although the behavior in this situation still needs to be defined, since the Logger is not fully initialized when Configuration tries wryting to it.

One approach would be to throw an exception or write an error message to the standard output when someone wants to use `Logger` before it's fully initialized.

Comment: I am using GetInstance with "static Logger l; return l;" so the solution for me is to use static boolean - "isInitialized" on GetInstance method (initialized to false) - and then init logger only in the first time.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize the logger with a bare minimum so you don't need the configuration at all.
Then when you have the configuration replace the logger.

If the config reader needs to log anything it will go to the bare minimum logger so you should at least dump it to stderr.

Also if you are in a multi-threaded environment make sure you use a shared_ptr and do an atomic swap to replace it with the propper one (in case some other module is logging when you need to swap).

Comment: What do you mean by "relplace the logger"? it is a singleton. I have to do the initialization right in the beginning of using the ctor. The access to the logger is through "getinstance()" function.

Comment: getInstance returns some static instance that you initialize. You can replace that static instance.

Comment: Where to replace it? in GetInstance() function?

Comment: I used kind of this solution. I used a default consturctor and a static bool on GetInstance function - isInit. If the object is not initialized - I init the logger with the configuration, etc. So - every time we call the logger - we skip the init section and just get the fully object with the configurations.